# How to make an RGB Slider to affect the colour of one Object

Tags: animation, node-editor

Is there a way separate objects of  R G B can be individual entities and affect one particular object (white cube).

Here's an example like a colour picker, you can slide the values and it makes up one colour.

https://tuneform.com/tools/color/rgb-color-creator

I have 3 cubes RED GREEN BLUE,

Red goes from black to Red 100%, Same for the Green and same for the Blue. I'm guessing this would be a node controller set up?

PS: is it possible to also add emission node so when the values go to full % of the colour it glows, and when the sliders go down to zero the emission glow fades?

[image]

Comment: My answer concentrates on the colors. Of course there might be a way for the glow as well.

Comment: It really depends on how you want the glow. You say, when the values go to full % of the color it glows, and when the sliders go down you want the emission to fade...? So basically you want a glow in relation to the colors percentage? Then when using a _Principled BSDF_, in my Version 1 just plug the color which goes into _Base Color_ in _Emission Color_ as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create a setup like this:

[image]

call the cubes: red, green, blue

add 3 custom scene properties, float, from 0 to 1, call them r, g, b:

[image]

add drivers to your custom properties:

[image]

do this accordingly to green and red

add a driver to your shaders base color:

[image]

like this:

[image]

do this accordingly to the other colors.

result:

[image]

Note: it helps if you use limit location constraints to your slider boxes like this:

[image]

Comment: Oh, you made the color change relative to the object's position... very nice.

Comment: i don't know whether he wants it that way...but i interpreted "slider" in his question that way....thanks! ;) ...and his link does work this way too...

Comment: Quite a good idea. I was just taking the objects as display to show how much color each channel has.