# Constrain to limit location

Tags: constraints

I'm trying to limit the location of the cubes, but regardless if I select local space or world space and try to set the limits, the cube (or any cube) will jump to the middle of the world. I need to limit the locations of each cube where they are situated.

Ps: I have set the origins to centre of each cube and also have applied all transforms in case that helped, but it did not.

[image]

Comment: Hello ! I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve, you set the minimal location to (0, 0, 0) and maximal location to (0, 0, 0) so it's only fair that the objects jump to the world origin, isn't it ? Or maybe you want to apply the transforms first so their origin is at world origin ? Or parent them to an empty at world origin ? Please add more details :)

Comment: Hi there. Even if I set the limit to 1, the cube or any cube will jump to the middle of the world: https://ibb.co/DKWxmN9

I was following this tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zCQYGJjkrMg, 2:20 
and he has set his to local space, and the object moves from its location back or forth, but I cannot do it.

Comment: Well yes, you are setting the max value to 1 along the Z axis, but the other ones are still constrained to 0, so you should be able to move your cube one unit along the Z axis but it will stay at x = 0 and y = 0

Comment: If you have a look at this tutorial, you'll see the cubes move along its Z axis on their own local space:, this is what I'm trying to achieve.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/253991/how-to-make-an-rgb-slider-to-affect-the-colour-of-one-object?noredirect=1#comment432895_253991

Comment: I assume it's because the cube's transforms are applied. Try CTRL + A > Location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are the constraints and how i did it:

[image]

you always need to change the y value to its original position, if you are using world space. The local space is only considered with bones or if parenting is used - if i understood that right.

Answer (score 1):

In the video that you have shown, bones are used, not objects. So you need to know that bones has initial positions defined in edit mode.

Local space is used if you have object parented to other object. In this example, cube is parented to empty(<kbd>P</kbd>) and parent inverse is cleared (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>):

[image]